# Execute Azure SQL Query from C on Samsung Gear S3 Smart Watch

Tags: c, sql-server, azure, tizen, samsung-gear

How can I execute an MSSQL query from within in a Gear S3 application?  I currently have C# code running to execute the query from a desktop app which looks like this:

```
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC_Data_Center.Properties.Settings.ABCDataCenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection newSQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        newSQLconnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select sum(weight) as int from harvest join field on (field.field_id = harvest.field_id) join location on (field.location_id = location.location_id) where cast(timestamp as date) = cast(@current_Time as date) and (location.account_id = @account_id)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_id", account_id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@current_Time", DateTime.Now);
        todaysHarvest.Text = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("N0");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Can I add this type of functionality to a smart watch application written in C using Tizen?

Comment: And you would want a direct-to-database connection from your wearable device *why*?

Comment: @DavidMakogon - "Ours is not to wonder why, ours is just to do or die"

Comment: @DavidMakogon I don't need a direct connection; I'd just like to populate a control using a value from this database.  What is the appropriate way to accomplish this?